# remembering of a select menu option with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 4 dynamically dependent select menus. The menus correspond to state, county, area, neighborhood. The dynamic dependence is achieved through a jQuery script. What I want to accomplish is to make the menus remember the last option selected by a user for each menu. So I thought that if I can grab the url parameters that would do the trick.
So I modified the script in this way....

```
getCounty: function (results) {
    if(!results) return;
    var allCounties = $("<option value=\"All\">All Counties </option>");
    counties.html(results);
    counties.prepend(allCounties);
    var w = $.query.get("county_id");
    if(w) {
        counties.val(w).attr('selected', true);
    } else {
        counties.val("All").attr('selected', true);
    }
```

Is the `$.query.get` function correct? Is there anything else wrong with my code? I have to admit I am not a jQuery expert...The code works just fine if I type

```
counties.val(3).attr('selected',true)
```

The third option of the select menu gets selected.

I resolved the problem by using

```
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,   function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
```

And after

```
  var county = getUrlVars()["county_id"];

  if (county)    
     counties.val(county).attr('selected',true);
  else 
      counties.val("All").attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: Why do you use `attr('selected',true)` for?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is "county_id", but i supose is a other menu, so maybe better :

```
getCounty: function (results) {
if(!results) return;
var allCounties = $("<option value=\"All\">All Counties </option>");
counties.html(results);
counties.append(allCounties); ///The all option first
var w = $('#county_id :selected').val(); ///w is the value of option selected of other combo
counties.find('option[value='+w+']').attr('selected', 'selected'); ///this find a option with value W, if exist mark like selected
}
```

Comment: I thought that since i use a .get function it would be clear that i am talking about a url parameter (The query executed the last time the user searched for something). Anyway i found a traditional javascript function that gets the url parameters and resolved the problem.Thanx you very much for taking the time answering to me.With your answer i enriched my jquery knowledges!